# MVC 2 with VS 2010 View Building Error: Feature 'anonymous types' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a shared project where I store all of my custom EditTemplates and DisplayTemplates.  This is a regular C# class library project with the views all tagged as embedded resources. The target framework of this project is ".Net Framework 4".

Inside the /Views/ folder I have included this web.config file so I get MVC 2 intellisense when working with the .aspx and .ascx files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc,     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />  
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"    type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Normally I have no problems with this setup but once and while I get an error when I compile my views:

> Error 3   Feature 'anonymous types'
>   cannot be used because it is not part
>   of the ISO-2 C# language
>   specification

for a template that looks like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
<%
    string displayText = string.Empty;

    if (Model != null)
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(Model.ToString()) != DateTime.MinValue)
            displayText = DateTime.Parse(Model.ToString()).ToShortDateString();
    }
%>

<%= Html.TextBox("", displayText, new { @class = "date-box" })%>
```

Most of the time this error just goes away.  I've learned to deal with it but right now its causing some issues.  Any idea of what causes the "Error 3 Feature 'anonymous types' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification" error and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow your IDE experience is causing the 4.0 C# compiler to be limited to features allowed in the 2.0 version of the compiler.  This can be done using the langversion switch.  For example

> csc /langversion:ISO-2 ...

Full Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4ckecs0.aspx

I'm unfamiliar with how compilation works for Asp.Net MVC but somewhere in your project system you've asked to be limited to the 2.0 framework.  My first guess would be to look at the project page of the project and make sure it's not targeting 2.0.

Comment: In my case I opened and view from an older version of the solution. I made a copy of all the files in a different folder and was using this as a reference during my conversion/refactoring/update process. Its curious that simply having this file opened caused a problem.

Answer (score 7):

I've faced with this issue, and have spent a lot of time, while figured out that App.Config file with empty configuration section in it was root of the evil. Simply **remove App.Config**, and all will work fine.

Comment: Any explanation or guessing on that?

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. You're right, after removing the app.config, it worked for me. However, I did also find out that if I copied the `system.web` configuration block from the web.config to the app.config, the error also disappeared. So if you need to have to app.config, try copying the configuration from your web.config to the app.config, and keep the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to change the project type

1. Unload the project
2. Edit project
3. Swap the project GUID for this

   *ProjectTypeGuids:* {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

(This is an MVC3 project)

Comment: Thanks, fixed it for me too.  Mine was a Class Library Project (VS2012, .NET Framework 4.5) in a plugin I wrote for NopCommerce, that employed razor views.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was ultimately caused by low disk space, presenting as a hailstorm of unusual and inexplicable random build errors.