# Razor views: Intellisense not working with C# 3 for class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I'm using class libraries in my ASP.NET MVC3 project.

To get it working I've done the following:

1. Using areas
2. Using a custom `VirtualPathProvider`
3. Using `BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly` for each assembly
4. Modified the csproj files to add support for Razor/wizards (`<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>`)
5. Copied the `web.config`s from the web project to each class library project

Everything works, except for intellisense in the razor views. I get warnings like this:

> Feature 'lambda expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification

The class libraries are set to use .NET 4.

There are some other questions here addressing the same issue

- [Razor intellisense error: Feature 'extension method' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568347/razor-intellisense-error-feature-extension-method-cannot-be-used-because-it-i)
- [MVC 2 with VS 2010 View Building Error: Feature 'anonymous types' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560773/mvc-2-with-vs-2010-view-building-error-feature-anonymous-types-cannot-be-used)

but I can't find anything that would force the compiler to run in 2.0 (and wouldn't that make my views fail at runtime?)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the *framework* version isn't the same as setting the *language* version.

I can reproduce the same error by creating a sample with a lambda expression and using:

```
csc /langversion:ISO-2 Test.cs
```

In Visual Studio, this is under Project Properties / Build / Advanced... / Language version. It does strike me as unusual that you'd have a Razor project fixed at ISO-2 though...

Comment: Everything builds fine and works when running the project. It's when I open a razor view from a class library in VStudio  that I get the errors. So it's not an incorrect build setting. `It does strike me as unusual that you'd have a Razor project fixed at ISO-2` I've not specified such. My problem is that I don't know why VStudio intellisense wants to compile the views as c# 2.0 when opening them in the editor.

Comment: @jgauffin: So even the code which causes the errors in VS works when you actually build? And this *doesn't* happen when you've got Razor views which aren't in class libraries? Sounds like it's probably "just" a bug in the view editor, but an annoying one :(

Comment: It's annoying yes. Looking at the other questions it seems like there are a solution (but their answers didn't help me track down the issue).

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I have this problem throughout my solution