# View Class Library // Razor Intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, intellisense, razorgenerator, razor-3

I want to create a usable View class library, including views using Razor.
I have troubles to implement Razor Intellisense in my views.

I have already done a lot of research to find a solution, including this blog : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/01/20/how-to-get-razor-intellisense-for-model-in-a-class-library-project.aspx and this related post: [Razor in class library, missing intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778987/razor-in-class-library-missing-intellisense), but nothing worked so far.

The last thing I tried was adding a web.config file in my View class library, but this did not enable Razor Intellisense.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Everything works when I am creating a MVC project instead of a Class Library to contain my Views... but I believe this would be a wrong thing to do. 
I already have a MVC Project which contains only my Controllers, and a Class Library that contains my Models.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue ?